# Highcharts grouped categories data csv

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, csv, highcharts

Hello together I have this example bar chart:

[image]

As you can see it has grouped categories

Now I want to be able to import the data through csv or xml.
I came across the data module of highcharts, but this is not designed for grouped categories I think.

What I achieved until now was this:

HTML Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="grouped-categories.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('data.csv', function(csv) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        data: {
            csv: csv,
            itemDelimiter: ';'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Roadmap'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                    text: 'Date'
                },
            labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '12px'
                    }
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            min : Date.UTC(2015, 10, 1),
            max : Date.UTC(2021, 01, 1),
            tickInterval: 30.41667 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This generates this bar chart:
[image]

Out of this csv:

```
Category,Date
Task 1,1483138800000
Task 2,1457046000000
Task 1,1467237600000
Task 1,1483138800000
```

Is it possible to generate a grouped categories bar chart out of csv or xml?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
Project1; Phase 1; Task 1, Value
Project1; Phase 2; Task 1, Value
Project1; Phase 2; Task 2, Value
Project1; Phase 3; Task 1, Value
```

An then try to get this output so highcharts can work with it:

```
categories: [{
      name: "Project 1",
      categories: [{
        name: "Phase 1",
        categories: ["Task 1"]
      }, {
        name: "Phase 2",
        categories: ["Task 1"]
      }, {
        name: "Phase 3",
        categories: ["Task 1", "Tas k2"]
      }]
```

Comment: that type of categories is more html and css than highcharts I think. you can have drilldown for this. so on first screen it would should counts for project1 and project2, then you can click on either to see different phases and their counts, which when clicked show counts for the tasks.

Comment: Grouped Categories plugin expects format of categories that is not supported directly by Highcharts. Data module is Highcharts official plugin, so it will not work like that by default or by using some available settings. You should parse your CSV data and create series data array and categories object using custom code. Let me know if you will have any problems with implementing this solution if you want some help with that.

Comment: @RahulSharma Drilldown ist one option. Is there a possiblity to use cvs data to import a drilldown ?

Comment: @KacperMadej it would be nice to get some help to implement a custom solutions with series. I never down that befor, I have to admit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grouped Categories](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin expects format of categories that is not supported directly by Highcharts. Data module is Highcharts official plugin, so it will not work like that by default or by using some available settings. Parsing CSV data - creating series data array and categories object could be the way to resolve the problem.

Here is example of what that parser might look like: http://jsfiddle.net/vboak5hr/

```
  $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var series = [];

    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
      var items = line.split(';'),
        hasThisCategory = false,
        categoryIndex = -1,
        categoryPath = options.xAxis.categories;

            //add data point to series data
      options.series[0].data.push(parseInt(items[3]));

            // I. level of categories
      Highcharts.each(categoryPath, function(category, i) {
        if (category.name === items[0]) {
          hasThisCategory = true;
          categoryIndex = i;
        }
      });
      if (!hasThisCategory) {
        categoryPath.push({
          name: items[0],
          categories: []
        });
      }
      if (categoryIndex === -1) categoryIndex = categoryPath.length - 1;

            // II. level of categories
      categoryPath = categoryPath[categoryIndex].categories;
      hasThisCategory = false;
      categoryIndex = -1;

      Highcharts.each(categoryPath, function(category, i) {
        if (category.name === items[1]) {
          hasThisCategory = true;
          categoryIndex = i;
        }
      });
      if (!hasThisCategory) {
        categoryPath.push({
          name: items[1],
          categories: []
        });
      }
      if (categoryIndex === -1) categoryIndex = categoryPath.length - 1;

            // III. level of categories
      categoryPath = categoryPath[categoryIndex].categories;
      hasThisCategory = false;
      categoryIndex = -1;

      Highcharts.each(categoryPath, function(category, i) {
        if (category === items[2]) {
          hasThisCategory = true;
        }
      });
      if (!hasThisCategory) {
        categoryPath.push(items[2]);
      }

    });

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
```

Comment: Wow I'am impressed. I thought you would give a hint, but that is perfectly working. Thank you.